# How can we perform Depth First Search on a tree on external memory in O(sort(N))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I know that we need an external stack data structure which takes O(1) I/O's for push() and pop() if buffer is full/empty,else no I/O's. And we have to use an adjacency list,which takes O(|V| + |E|/B) on general graphs.(I'm not sure but i assume that it takes O(|V|) on trees)

Comment: So, concluding your question, you ask for the impossible?

Comment: Well, according to my homework it isn't impossible.
here:  ftp://ftp.math.ethz.ch/EMIS/journals/JGAA/accepted/2003/Arge%2B2003.7.2.pdf  
it says "BFS  and  DFS  can  be  solved in O(sort(N)) I/Os on trees [10, 12] and outerplanar graphs [20]" . The only question is how?